# Should you separate Report Parts in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I'm designing some reports in SSRS 2008 R2. When I publish these reports to my SSRS server, it stores my assets, variables and etc in a directory called "Report Parts". It seems SSRS does this for every report even though I can specify separate folders per report.

SO the question is: should I separate my report parts per report OR is it safe to jam all my report parts into one directory?

I do a lot of programming. My gut says to separate them always, but I figured I would ask before I find myself with a load of report parts that have the same names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, If you have report parts that are going to be used in multiple reports, it is bad practice to have duplicates (in my opinion). If you have to make an update, then you will have to update each report part separately and run the risk of missing updating one, plus it will take you a lot longer.

For shared report parts you should put them all in a shared folder(s). It does make sense to separate them into different folders though if you're going to have a lot of them, so they are easier to manage.

Comment: Didn't realize this was more opinion based, but your answer makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Fastidious Everyone has their own methods of doing things, and different situations. Some situations may call for duplicating work, but it rarely makes sense..  I think `DRY` applies here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: To make it even more clear: the entire point of report parts is DRY. Build one bar chart, store it in one place, share it with 10 different reports passing a different parameter to it to filter on one commodity / department / region, etc. etc..

Comment: @KyleHale Yes, that's an excellent point. Report parts are designed to make maintenance and usage easier.